# Is it possible to parse and output an XML document to HTML in document order using PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml

I apologize if this is something that has been discussed thoroughly here. I spent a good amount of time searching for an answer and can't seem to dig a definitive one up. Also, I'm pretty much an amateur when it comes to PHP.

I have an XML document that I'm trying to render as HTML using PHP. The XML is actually "theoretically" used for single-sourcing, meaning the hope is for using it as a source for producing both PDF and HTML output. So, the XML is actually made up of elements that serve as the parts of a manual. See below:

```
<topic>
   <title>Some topic.</title>
   <caution>
      <para>Cautionary note 1.</para>
   </caution>
   <para>Paragraph 1</para>
   <caution>
      <para>Cautionary note 2.</para>
   </caution>
   <para>Paragraph 2</para>
   <figure>
      <graphic src="../some_path"/>
   </figure>
</topic>
```

For PDF, I plan on writing an XSLT transform. For HTML, I have a script that successfully converts all the elements of the XML into HTML. The problem is, it seems to be converting the XML as parsed arrays. The above example renders with (using HTML equivalents):

- All figure elements at the top.
- All para elements in the middle (excluding para elements within the caution elements).
- All caution elements at the bottom.

So, the document order is not preserved. Since this source is used to put together a manual, the document order is important.

My question: Is it possible to use PHP to parse XML into HTML and preserve document order? Again, I'm pretty much a PHP amateur so I apologize if my question seems obtuse. Any advice or pointers is welcome.

*EDITED TO ADD SOME OF THE PHP*

The PHP script is pretty lengthy so I will try to include as much of the relevant bits as possible.

In terms of the cautionary notes, the script initially defines a function:

```
//Display the cautions from the xml
        function display_cautions($cautions)
        {
            foreach( $cautions as $caution )
            {
                foreach( $caution->para as $cautionpara )
                {
                    printf("<p class='Text'>");
                    foreach( $cautionpara->{'attention-icon'} as $attentionicon )
                    {
                        printf("<img src='../../images/%s' width='25px' height='25px'>", htmlspecialchars($attentionicon['srcfile']));
                    }
                    $cautionpara = str_ireplace('<emph>', '<b>', $cautionpara);
                    $cautionpara = str_ireplace('</emph>', '</b>', $cautionpara);
                    printf("%s</p>", htmlspecialchars($cautionpara));
                }
            }
        }
```

Then it constructs the document:

```
if (isset($_GET['ID']))  
        {
            $introsections = $doc->{'intro-section'};
            //printf("got here 1");
            foreach( $introsections as $introsection )
            {
                //printf("got here 2");
                $sectno = $introsection['sect-no'];
                if ($sectno == $_GET['ID'])
                {
                    $smtitle = $introsection->title->nodeValue;
                    $introgenerals = $introsection->{'intro-general'};
                    foreach( $introgenerals as $introgeneral )
                    {
                        //printf("got here 3");
                        $smtitle = $introgeneral->title;
                        $introid = $introgeneral['id'];
                        //Display the title
                        printf("<h2>%s</h2>", htmlspecialchars($smtitle));
                            //Match found
                            $topics = $introgeneral->topic;
                            foreach( $topics as $topic )
                            {
                                //Display the title
                                printf("<p class='Text12Bold'>%s</p>", htmlspecialchars($topic->title));
                                $topicparas = $topic->para;
                                //Get all the paragraphs
                                foreach( $topicparas as $topicpara )
                                {
                                    //MH added: code to include xrefs here
                                    //check for xrefs in this para
                                    $xrefs = $topicpara->xref;
                                    if (simple_xml_count($xrefs) > 0) {
                                        //printf("<p class='Text'>%s</p>\n", htmlspecialchars($topicpara));
                                        display_referral_links($xrefs, $topicpara);
                                    } else {
                                        $topicpara = str_ireplace('<emph>', '<b>', $topicpara);
                                        $topicpara = str_ireplace('</emph>', '</b>', $topicpara);
                                        ?>
                                        <p class='Text'><?php printf($topicpara) ?></p>

                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
```

Then it calls the caution function:

```
//Get all the cautions with images where applicable
display_cautions($topic->caution);
```

In between the document construction and the function call, it constructs tables, subtopics and figures. Similar functions are in place for warnings, notes, and lists.

Comment: You created that xml? In PHP caution will be render as `array ( "caution" => array ( 0 => array ( "para" => "Cautionary note 1."), 1 => array ( "para" => "Cautionary note 2.")))` Which is normal because of the xml you gave... How are you parsing it? Can you put here the code that creates the array?

Comment: Edited to include some of the PHP. I actually inherited this stuff. So, how the XML was constructed was out of my hands. Long-term I'll be transforming it into something else as I don't think it was constructed against any sort of schema.

Comment: Why not use XSLT for both?

Comment: Yeah, fair question. That likely is the direction I'll be going with this. For short-term (meaning before end of week), I'm just trying to work with what I have.